# ASP.NET DropDownList inside ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey guys i need your helps.. Why i cant refer for my veriable to the DropDownList control in the code-behind? I would add that the control is in the control of another in a ListView but when the DropDownList control will be is out of  the ListView I can refer to it. Where is the Devil??. Regards

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="view.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sites_view" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="center" Runat="Server">


    <form id="formluarz" method="post" action="">
        <div id="form-view">
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:practiceConnectionString %>" 
                  SelectCommand="SELECT k.idKlienci, k.imie, k.nazwisko, k.adres, k.miasto, r.idRezerwacje, r.data, r.godzina, r.idKlienci FROM klienci AS k INNER JOIN rezerwacje AS r ON k.idKlienci = r.idKlienci"
                  UpdateCommand="UPDATE Klienci SET imie = @imie, nazwisko = @nazwisko, adres = @adres, miasto = @miasto  WHERE (idKlienci = @IdKlienci)UPDATE rezerwacje SET data = @data, godzina = @godzina  WHERE (idRezerwacje = @idRezerwacje)"               
               ></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  DataKeyNames="idRezerwacje, idKlienci" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" >    
             <LayoutTemplate>              
                  <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="10" >
                                <Fields>
                                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ButtonCssClass="pagin" ShowFirstPageButton="true"/>
                                    <asp:NumericPagerField  NumericButtonCssClass="pagin" CurrentPageLabelCssClass="pagin"/>                                  
                                </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
                <table cellpadding="2" runat="server" id="tblDepartments" width="640px" cellspacing="1">

                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server" class="TableHeader">
                        <td id="Td1" runat="server">Edycja</td>                                     
                        <td id="Td2" runat="server">imie</td>                     
                        <td id="Td3" runat="server">nazwisko</td> 
                        <td id="Td7" runat="server">adres</td>                       
                        <td id="Td8" runat="server">miasto</td>                              
                        <td id="Td5" runat="server">data</td>                       
                        <td id="Td6" runat="server">godzina</td>                                                                  

                    </tr>              
                     <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                 </table>
             </LayoutTemplate>   
             <EditItemTemplate>
               <tr >
                <td>
                  <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                  <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>

                <td >
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="NameLabel" AssociatedControlID="NameTextBox" 
                    Text="Imie" Font-Bold="true"/><br />
                  <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("imie") %>' />
                </td>
                <td >
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="GroupNameLabel" AssociatedControlID="SurnameTextBox" 
                    Text="Nazwisko" Font-Bold="true" /><br />
                  <asp:TextBox ID="SurnameTextBox" runat="server"  Width="150px" Text='<%#Bind("nazwisko") %>' />
                  <br />
                </td>
                <td >
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" AssociatedControlID="AdressTextBox" 
                    Text="Adres" Font-Bold="true" /><br />
                  <asp:TextBox ID="AdressTextBox" runat="server"  Width="150px" Text='<%#Bind("adres") %>' />
                  <br />
                </td>
                <td >
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" AssociatedControlID="CityTextBox" 
                    Text="Miasto" Font-Bold="true" /><br />
                  <asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server"  Width="150px" Text='<%#Bind("miasto") %>' />
                  <br />
                </td>
                <td class="EditItem">

                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" AssociatedControlID="DateTextBox" 
                    Text="Data" Font-Bold="true" /><br />
                    <div id="ab">
                 <div id="a"><asp:TextBox ID="DateTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="100px" Text='<%#Bind("data") %>' /></div><div id="b"><asp:image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="image" style="cursor:hand;" onclick="PopupDatePicker('DateTextBox')" ImageUrl="~/image/ikon.png" /></div></div>

                </td>
                 <td >
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label4" 
                    Text="Godzina" Font-Bold="true" /><br />
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  >                    
                     </asp:DropDownList>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>   
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <tr  runat="server">
                    <td>
                      <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>                 
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("imie") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="SurnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("nazwisko") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="AdressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("adres") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("miasto") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="DataLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("data") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="TimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("godzina") %>' />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>

        </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ktr, mtr;
    for (int k = 0; k < 24; k++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < 60; m = m + 5)
        {

            if (k < 10)
            {
                ktr = "0" + k.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ktr = k.ToString();
            }
            if (m < 10)
            {
                mtr = "0" + m.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                mtr = m.ToString();
            }

            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(ktr + ":" + mtr)); //cant refer :(

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code, both the `.aspx` file and the `.aspx.cs` file where you're having difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to check if you really trigger that Page_Load event with a simple break point. 
Secondly I highly recommend you override The "OnLoad" event instead of "Page_Load".

You would have something like this in the .aspx.cs:

```
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    string ktr, mtr;
    for (int k = 0; k < 24; k++)
    {
      for (int m = 0; m < 60; m = m + 5)
      {
        if (k < 10)
        {
            ktr = "0" + k.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ktr = k.ToString();
        }
        if (m < 10)
        {
            mtr = "0" + m.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            mtr = m.ToString();
        }

        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(ktr + ":" + mtr)); 

      }
   } 
}
```